# Using R for effect sizes (and ANOVA) in Likert scales

Tags: r

I want to find the effect sizes between Likert scale responses similar to the one in the pic (with pairwise comparisons for each of the countries). How could I do that in R? In my study I have four countries with 750 participants over all. Should I just be doing Spearman's Rho, or a Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test instead?? I couldn't be more lost and any help would be greatly appreciated.
[Example of pairwise comparisons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWh4w.jpg)

Comment: StackOverflow is typically for questions regarding code. Part of this question is related to which statistical test is appropriate and should be asked in the CrossValidated forum at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the code needed to do the analysis in R, here is an example set of question data for 4 countries and then running an ANOVA against them to determine if there are significant differences in question responses between countries.

```
my_survey_dat <- data.frame(country=rep(c('USA', 'Germany', 'Netherlands', 'Denmark')), 
                            likert_question = c(4,3,5,4,2,3,4,3,3,5,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,3,2,3))

model <- lm(likert_question ~ country, data = my_survey_dat)

anova(model)

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: likert_question
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
country    3    0.4 0.13333  0.1301 0.9408
Residuals 16   16.4 1.02500
```

In your example there is some output on the statistical significance. In this case it would read *F*(3,16) = 0.1301, *p*=.9408